# Sharing image via intent using file provider makes error "Failed to find configured root that contains "

Tags: android

I have a bitmap image ,which will be saved using filesDir(). When i try to access the bitmap for sharing purpose i am getting error. The error is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/ms.ss.ss/files/prediciton_Image.png
```

My Manifest configruation is

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

And my provider_path file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="prediciton_Image.png" path="files/"/>
 </paths>
```

And here is the code for handling the bitmap

```
 private void shareBitmap (Bitmap bitmap,String fileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), fileName + ".png");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
       Uri photoUri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(PredictionWebView.this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",file);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(     android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,photoUri );
        intent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I know i have mistyped somewhere. Can you please figure it out where the error is?

Comment: `path="files/"`. Change to `path="."`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
        android:exported="false"
```

to

```
        android:exported="true"
```